# SQL Query for retrieving unique identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table M1 and it has two fields M_ID and Indicator. I have to write a SQL query in order to retrieve the data for every individual M_ID and will use the update statement after the successful processing.

Example: `M_ID` will have values like `1,2,3,4` etc.

Table structure:

- `M1` : `M_ID, F1, F2, F3, UpdateIndicator`

F* are the columns.

During every execution of query I need to retrieve the details of individual `M_ID`. I can't hardcode the `M_ID` value in the query.

I don't have much exposure towards SQL and as part of integrating a DATA BASE system I just use the query in my system to retrieve the data.

I tried with

```
select * from M1
```

using `GROUPBY` with the minimal knowledge I have in SQL but it is returning all the `M_ID`'s in the database.

The output should look like below:

If `M_ID` has values like `1,2,3,4`, my SQL query should return for

- 1st instance as `row<1,F1,F2,F3,UpdateIndicator>`
- 2nd instance as `row<2,F4,F5,F6,UpdateIndicator>`

and so on..

Comment: In database questions it is necessary to tell which database engine you are using - Oracle, MS SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres, etc. - and specify it's version. Also try to describe your task from higher perspective - may be someone can suggest better solution for it.

Comment: Also show some code, that you use to manipulate the database. If you're using C# and native SqlClient, I suggest using SqlCommand with parameters for your dynamic ID's

Answer (score 0):

Get data by M_ID:

```
SELECT * FROM M1 WHERE M_ID=1
```

Get all M_ID's:

```
SELECT M_ID FROM M1
```

Maybe, you can optimize your program this way:

```
/* This will apply updates to all fields that have Indicator field set */
UPDATE M1 SET /* any fields updates */ WHERE UpdateIndicator=1

/** 
 * EXAMPLE:
 * Inrement F1 and decrement F2 on each record that requires update
 */
UPDATE M1 SET F1=F1+1, F2=F2-1 WHERE UpdateIndicator=1
```

Comment: Hi, As I mentioned I can't pass the value of M_ID.It should be dynamic.

Comment: So, where it comes from?